# lock statement and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, locking

Is it plausable to use a lock for a POST within MVC? Is there situation like using a webfarm that would invalidate the lock? I usually use database locks but my particular situation is pretty difficult to manage and its simpler to use a Monitor. I dont want to get into discussing why I need a lock just want to know if there are situations when it wont work as desired.

```
private static object Lockable = new Object(); 
public ActionResult Submit() 
{
     lock(Lockable)
     {


     }   
}
```

Comment: A webfarm wouldn't invalidate the lock, it only locks a local object, but I have needed to use locks on occasion for smtp messages.

Comment: Lock is only used to lock between threads in the same process in the same appdomain on the same server. So other servers are not influenced by a lock.

I think you are looking for database transactions. Google the SqlTransaction class when using ADO. In Entity Framework you could use TransactionScope to perform this.

Comment: @C.Zonnenberg I was hoping not to deal with the database metal (usually I would) as this is slightly complex. I might have to though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve a lock over a webfarm you need to have a shared resource on the network (such as a cache server), and you need to use that to achieve webfarm-safe locking. I think that's the simplest solution.

You can also isolate the component you want to serialize calls to and access to it over network.

There is another option of creating a MSDTC compliant component that can enlist into distributed transactions so all callers are enforced to serialize their calls. However that requires setting up all environment to work with MSDTC, Enterprise Services etc.

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself, in the case of few web servers / different processes, your lock will only work for the current process, which means it wont affect other running instances of ur application, if such exist.